# Pass list by reference in python through recursion

Tags: python, list, pointers, recursion, reference

I am using a recursive function call to traverse a tree and I want to add the locations of valuable nodes to a master list. My current method is to use a global. How do I pass this list by reference instead (or solve this in another way without globals)

```
hcList = []

def expand(node):
    global hcList

    if node.hasTreasure():
        hcList.append(node)
    if not node.end():
        expand(node.next())

global hcList
expand(startnode)
hcList.filter()
```

Anyway to do something like below without using a hairy global? My actual code is much messier with globals but the concepts are the same. The code below doesn't work the way I want it to. Namely, hcList is empty.

```
def expand(node, hcList):      
    if node.hasTreasure():
        hcList.append(node)
    if not node.end():
        expand(node.next(), hcList)

hcList = []
expand(startnode, hcList)
hcList.filter()
```

Comment: Your bottom `expand` should work.  The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: What error do you get? There is no 'filter' method on list, so that's a problem, is that it?

Comment: Lists are *always* passed by reference, so I agree with @roippi. The problem lies with the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Yep I verified the bottom does work. And I found the original error. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For recursion, it is frequently simpler to return the new value

```
def expand(node, hcList):
    if node.hasTreasure:
         hcList.append(node)
    if node.end():
         return hcList
    return expand(node.next(), hcList)

hcList = expand(startnode, [])
hcList.filter() # not sure why this was in the OP
```

If your list is very deep, you may have a lot on the stack, but good tail recursion can optimize that away.